# What is the simplest way to send form data to spring boot?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I've tried it a couple different ways but keep getting the *There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403)* error.  Here is the html method:

**HTML**

```
    <form method="post" action="/forms">
        <p>Enter User Id : <input type="text" name="userId"/></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
    </form>
```

Here is the javascript/jquery method:

**javascript and jquery**

```
    <form method="post" action="postPosts()">
        <p>Enter User Id : <input type="text" name="userId"/></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
    </form>
```

In the scripts section:

```
  var postPosts = function() {
      console.log("Im in postPosts");
      $.post("/posts", function(data) {
          console.log(data);
      })
  }
```

The console.log is not even being hit so the error is happening before that.  Suggestions?

Comment: change `action="postPosts()"` to `onsubmit="postPosts()"` also you need to prevent default submission of form if you are using ajax .

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way I guess would be with just HTML like so:

```
<form method="post" action="posts">
    <label>Enter User Id : <input type="text" name="userId"/></label>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

the `<form method="post" action="/posts">` line says that the form will send a POST request to the `post` route.

so basically that's not what causes the problem in your code it's probably that you don't have that route handled in your server and that's why you see that [403 error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403#:%7E:text=The%20HTTP%20403%20Forbidden%20client,authenticating%20will%20make%20no%20difference.).

> The HTTP 403 Forbidden client error status response code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.

Comment: `/post` is redundant. `post` will do.

Comment: Sarr, sadly, same error with your suggestion.  @Spectric - /posts is the URI to a blog posting web service

Comment: I edited my answer. according to your error, you don't really  handle that route in your server-side code

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought too but the error appears to be happening even before it goes to the server.  The javascript method has the line "console.log("Im in postPosts");" which doesn't output anything.

Comment: A form action set to a JavaScript function is not widely supported. it probably won't invoke the JS function in the JS example and will try to find a route like that in the server

Comment: Its the same way I did 5 other GET calls on this project which worked fine.